# Jquery reset select to default whenever another select is changed not working in AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, search, dropdown

I'm trying to reset a drop down select field and update the search url parameters when another dropdown is selected.

I'm using the Search and Filter Pro plugin for wordpress with AJAX enabled so when i search, the URL changes automatically and only displays the posts assigned to that taxonomy.

I've used their ajax start hook to reset the county dropdown when the Region dropdown is selected. This works but now the County dropdown doesn't fire independently and just doesn't do anything.

This is the code i'm working on at the moment:

```
   (function ( $ ) {
    "use strict";

    jQuery(document).on("sf:ajaxstart", ".searchandfilter", function(){

      var tax1 = jQuery('.sf-field-taxonomy-regions select').val();

      if(location.search.search('_sft_regions='+tax1) == -1) {
        jQuery('.sf-field-taxonomy-counties select').val('');
      }


});
}(jQuery));

<form data-sf-form-id='88' data-is-rtl='0' data-maintain-state='1' data-results-url='https://rslcloud.co.uk/properties-for-sale/' data-ajax-url='https://rslcloud.co.uk/properties-for-sale/?sf_data=all' data-ajax-form-url='https://rslcloud.co.uk/?sfid=88&amp;sf_action=get_data&amp;sf_data=form' data-display-result-method='archive' data-use-history-api='1' data-template-loaded='1' data-lang-code='' data-ajax='1' data-ajax-data-type='html' data-ajax-target='#content' data-ajax-pagination-type='normal' data-ajax-links-selector='.pagination a' data-update-ajax-url='1' data-only-results-ajax='1' data-scroll-to-pos='0' data-init-paged='1' data-auto-update='1' data-auto-count='1' data-auto-count-refresh-mode='1' action='https://rslcloud.co.uk/properties-for-sale/' method='post' class='searchandfilter' id='search-filter-form-88' autocomplete='off' data-instance-count='1'><ul><li class="sf-field-taxonomy-regions" data-sf-field-name="_sft_regions" data-sf-field-type="taxonomy" data-sf-field-input-type="select">     <label>
        <span class="screen-reader-text">Browse Regions</span>      <select name="_sft_regions[]" class="sf-input-select" title="Browse Regions">

                        <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-0 sf-option-active" selected="selected" data-sf-count="0" data-sf-depth="0" value="">All Regions</option>
                        <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-2" data-sf-count="6" data-sf-depth="0" value="east-midlands">East Midlands</option>
                        <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-3" data-sf-count="8" data-sf-depth="0" value="north-west">North West</option>
                        <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-5" data-sf-count="3" data-sf-depth="0" value="south">South</option>
                        <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-4" data-sf-count="5" data-sf-depth="0" value="south-east">South East</option>
                        <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-6" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="0" value="wales">Wales</option>
                        <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-7" data-sf-count="9" data-sf-depth="0" value="west-midlands">West Midlands</option>
                    </select>
        </label>        </li><li class="sf-field-taxonomy-counties" data-sf-field-name="_sft_counties" data-sf-field-type="taxonomy" data-sf-field-input-type="select">     <label>
        <span class="screen-reader-text">Browse Counties</span>     <select name="_sft_counties[]" class="sf-input-select" title="Browse Counties">

                        <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-0 sf-option-active" selected="selected" data-sf-count="0" data-sf-depth="0" value="">All Counties</option>
                        <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-8" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="0" value="bedfordshire">Bedfordshire</option>
                        <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-9" data-sf-count="2" data-sf-depth="0" value="berkshire">Berkshire</option>
                        <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-10" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="0" value="buckinghamshire">Buckinghamshire</option>
                        <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-11" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="0" value="cambridgeshire">Cambridgeshire</option>
                        <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-12" data-sf-count="2" data-sf-depth="0" value="cheshire">Cheshire</option>
                        <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-13" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="0" value="conwy">Conwy</option>
                        <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-14" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="0" value="dorset">Dorset</option>
                        <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-15" data-sf-count="3" data-sf-depth="0" value="east-sussex">East Sussex</option>
                        <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-16" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="0" value="lancashire">Lancashire</option>
                        <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-17" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="0" value="leicestershire">Leicestershire</option>
                        <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-18" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="0" value="lincolnshire">Lincolnshire</option>
                        <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-19" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="0" value="london">London</option>
                        <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-20" data-sf-count="4" data-sf-depth="0" value="merseyside">Merseyside</option>
                        <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-21" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="0" value="middlesex">Middlesex</option>
                        <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-22" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="0" value="northamptonshire">Northamptonshire</option>
                        <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-23" data-sf-count="2" data-sf-depth="0" value="warwickshire">Warwickshire</option>
                        <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-24" data-sf-count="5" data-sf-depth="0" value="west-midlands">West Midlands</option>
                        <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-25" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="0" value="wiltshire">Wiltshire</option>
                        <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-26" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="0" value="wirral">Wirral</option>
                        <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-27" data-sf-count="2" data-sf-depth="0" value="worcestershire">Worcestershire</option>
                    </select>
        </label>        </li></ul></form>        
       <select name="choose-court" onchange="location = this.value;">
       <option>Choose Court</option>
                      <option value="ashby-court">Ashby Court</option>
                          <option value="blake-court">Blake Court</option>
                          <option value="blundellsands-classic">Blundellsands Classic Court</option>
                          <option value="boat-lane-court">Boat Lane Court</option>
                          <option value="bowling-green-court">Bowling Green Court</option>
                          <option value="burcot-court">Burcot Court</option>
                          <option value="bushmead-court">Bushmead Court</option>
                          <option value="carrs-court">Carrs Court</option>
                          <option value="cathedral-green-court">Cathedral Green Court</option>
                          <option value="deerhurst-court">Deerhurst Court</option>
                          <option value="dovehouse-court">Dovehouse Court</option>
                          <option value="elizabeth-court">Elizabeth Court</option>
                          <option value="emmbrook-court">Emmbrook Court</option>
                          <option value="forum-court">Forum Court</option>
                          <option value="fullerton-court">Fullerton Court</option>
                          <option value="gorselands-court">Gorselands Court</option>
                          <option value="greyfriars-court">Greyfriars Court</option>
                          <option value="kennet-court">Kennet Court</option>
                          <option value="king-richard-court">King Richard Court</option>
                          <option value="margaret-court">Margaret Court</option>
                          <option value="marlborough-court">Marlborough Court</option>
                          <option value="melton-court">Melton Court</option>
                          <option value="minster-court">Minster Court</option>
                          <option value="oaktree-court">Oaktree Court</option>
                          <option value="osborne-court">Osborne Court</option>
                          <option value="pinner-court">Pinner Court</option>
                          <option value="plymouth-court">Plymouth Court</option>
                          <option value="plymouth-court-2">Plymouth Court</option>
                          <option value="priory-court">Priory Court</option>
                          <option value="saxon-court">Saxon Court</option>
                          <option value="st-georges-court">St Georges Court</option>
                          <option value="tannery-court">Tannery Court</option>
                          <option value="tiddington-court">Tiddington Court</option>
                     </select>
</div>
```

rslcloud.co.uk/properties-for-sale/

Does anyone know why the county dropdown isn't working now?

Comment: Paste your html too so that we can check

Comment: Really need to emphasis the issue.. I did this, and get that.. Or I want this.. But get that..

Comment: Your counties doesnt work because it is looking at Regions. If regions is default / no value, then it doesnt work.

Comment: The issue was when i selected a County and then  a region the results did not reset themselves. As i'm using the Search and Filter Pro plugin most of the coding is within Wordpress through a UI. The code works but for some reason the when i just try and search counties it doesn't search.

Comment: @Shaun its looking at your Regions for a value. See if there is a exempt setting you can set on your counties so that it can look without Regions being set.. If regions has to be set, you may need to do this in steps.. Step 1, choose a region.. etc etc..

Comment: Thanks for you help Cam, I can't see anything which would make it exempt but i'll keep trying.

Comment: I think the counties is already exempt. They're two separate taxonomies so i'm not sure why it would need to look with Regions being set?

Comment: @AlivetoDie I've added the HTML. Does this help?